# Rails Mechanize two part form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mechanize

I have a simple task that I want to do using mechanize, but the website has a login page that asks for your email, then once you have input it and clicked the submit, it asks for your password on the same page. How would I handle the second submit on the same page?

I tried this:
task :estimatesite => :environment do
      require 'mechanize'

```
  mechanize = Mechanize.new

  page = mechanize.get('https://estimatesite.com/auth/login')

  form = page.forms.first

  form['user_search_email[email]'] = 'myemail@email.com'

  form['check_distinct_user_password[plainPassword]'] = 'mypassword'

  page = form.submit

end
```

it looks something like this:

```
task :estimatesite => :environment do
  require 'mechanize'

  mechanize = Mechanize.new

  page = mechanize.get('https://estimatesite.com/auth/login')

  form = page.forms.first

  form['user_search_email[email]'] = 'myemail@email.com'
page = form.submit

  form['check_distinct_user_password[plainPassword]'] = 'mypassword'

  page = form.submit

end
```

but neither seems to work

Comment: make sure `https://estimatesite.com/auth/login` is working as i have seen this link is broken.

Comment: sorry this is an example:)

Comment: Please check the correction in your example, below as well as follow up the reference link, hopefully it will help you. also make sure you are using working link to test your example.

Comment: Were i able to solve your issue? Feel free to upvote/accept the answer if it helped you.?

Answer (score 0):

```
task :estimatesite => :environment do
  require 'mechanize'

  agent = WWW::Mechanize.new

  agent.get('https://estimatesite.com/auth/login')

  form = agent.page.forms.first

  form['user_search_email[email]'] = 'myemail@email.com''
  form.submit

  form['check_distinct_user_password[plainPassword]'] = 'mypassword'

  form.submit
end
```

Reference =>

http://railscasts.com/episodes/191-mechanize?autoplay=true

Comment: I have used this but when i test with a page.css('h2') I get the login page